# how to add selected object in string and use another time when objects are not selected for make selection again, in MEL

Tags: maya, mel

I want to add some selected controller of a character in a string and use this string for selecting the controllers again with a GUI button.

Thanks.

Comment: This is probably the first thing any animator learns. You will find tonnes of easy tutorials online. Google and thou shall find. Hint: character controller select shelf button.

Comment: http://mayaspiral.blogspot.ca/2012/03/workflow-animation-tips-and-tricks.html?m=1

Comment: Please do your prior research before posting a question on this site.

Answer (score 1):

I've found this website to help a great deal with learning MEL script.

http://nccastaff.bournemouth.ac.uk/jmacey/RobTheBloke/www/mel/

You want to:
Enable script editor in Maya
Go to history at the top of the window
Select ECHO COMMANDS
Select your controller for the character and understand what the code is saying

From here, copy that code and paste it up in your script shelf.

I.E.

[controller is called nCircle1, you have found this out through the process I've given you]

```
select -replace "nCircle1"; //copy this into your shelf OR

string $controller = `ls -sl`;
select $controller[0];
```

If you want to learn more about this stuff, I suggest you visit that site and learn about scripting.

**Do your research before coming to StackOverflow. It'll make your experience with the community a whole lot better. This question is extremely simple and could be solved on your own, without asking anyone for help.**